# Failing with '=""' when updating MiKTeX packages

Tags: packages, miktex

I have some problem with my MiKTeX and I want to now update some packages. 
[image]

But it seems I cannot connect to the server.
[image]

At the same time, I find I cannot connect to http://miktex.org/ either.
[image]

Or use miktex-update-admin.exe
[image]

Could anyone help me with my problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Miktex maintainer announced some days ago that the miktex server will be down on 9 may and 10 may.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issues at the moment, I think the problem is on their side. You can check if a site is down here: http://www.websitenotworking.com/miktex.org.

It reports the website as not working atm.

My error is ="connect failed in tcp_connect()" but since we can't access the miktex.org site I think we have the same source.